# How do I create two rows from one row SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do I make two rows from one row using a select query?

Here is an example

```
  create table timecards 
  (employeeid nvarchar(10) not null,
  regulartime int null,
  overtime int null)

  insert into timecards
  values ('A', 8, 1)
```

I would like the results to be

```
 A,8
 A,1
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Suggested good habits (using sql since early 1980's Oracle 2): in create table always explicitly declare null or not null for columns. Databases often have a systemwide or session level setting that changes the default nullability. It can wreck your schema if the default is not what you think. And dinosaurs like me will know your intent when reading your code. Doesn't matter in this case, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways....how about

```
select employeeid, regulartime as somekindatime
from timecards
union all
select employeeid, overtime
from timecards
```

The ALL keyword just informs SQL that we don't want to sort and eliminate duplicates. Can save time unless you actually want to eliminate duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can `unpivot` the table. `null` values in any of the columns would be eliminated in this case.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2b60/1)

```
select employeeid, tm
from 
(select employeeid,regulartime,overtime from timecard) t
UNPIVOT
(tm for id in (regulartime,overtime)
) as x
```